# Declarabes in Spring application using Rabbit MQ

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am using spring aqmp version 2.2.6 to create multiple binding to a topic exchange. 
I understand from the discussion and the reference document that i can use declarables .[Spring AMQP: Creating multiple queues dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350102/spring-amqp-creating-multiple-queues-dynamically)

But in my case i will have the routing keys in the application config as comma seperated and ever growing .
How would i use the config to create the declarable bean dynamically. ?
below is application config entry.
rabbit.MQ_SUBSCRIBER_ROUTING_KEY = my.#,test.#

The routing key will be added as in when required by service .

Shoud i loop the rabbit.MQ_SUBSCRIBER_ROUTING_KEY and call bean function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my.queues=foo,bar,baz
```

Spring can convert that to a `List<String>`.

```java
@Bean
public Declarables queues(@Value("${my.queues}") List<String> queues) {
    return new Declarables(queues
            .stream()
            .map(q -> new Queue(q))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new Queue[0]));
}
```

**EDIT**

For the complete picture:

```java
@Bean
public Declarables declarables(@Value("${my.queues}") List<String> queues,
        @Value("${my.exchange}") String exch, 
        @Value("${my.routing.keys}") List<String> routingKeys) {

    List<Declarable> declarables = queues
                    .stream()
                    .map(q -> new Queue(q))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    declarables.add(new DirectExchange(exch));
    for (int i = 0; i < routingKeys.size(); i++) {
        declarables.add(new Binding(queues.get(i), DestinationType.QUEUE, exch, 
                routingKeys.get(i), null));
    }
    return new Declarables(declarables
            .toArray(new Declarable[0]));
}
```

```
my.queues=foo,bar,baz
my.exchange=qux
my.routing.keys=rk1,rk2,rk3
```

Comment: Tried it for Queue, my post was for binding though. Need to create binding like below , but k2 and k3 in below code  are read from config rabbit.routingkey = my.#,test.# in my case.
rabbit.routingkey will add new routing key as in when new requirement comes in.

@Bean
    public Declarables bs() {
        return new Declarables(
                new Binding("q2", DestinationType.QUEUE, "e2", "k2", null),
                new Binding("q3", DestinationType.QUEUE, "e3", "k3", null));

Comment: Don't put code in comments; as you can see, it's hard to read. Queue was just an example; the same technique can be used for bindings; it's not clear from your comment whether you still have a problem.

Comment: Yes Gary, I am still facing issue in loading the binding bean as the queue example provided. Returning new Declarables with bindings converted to array is not creating the bindings as expected in rabbit. Can you post code example for binding please.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need more help, but I added a more complete example to my answer.